# Tenses for "I will count on seeing you in Paris, especially since I always wanted to go there"

Tags: temps-grammatical, concordance-des-temps

I am wondering about the right tenses to use when translating this into French. My attempt:

```
Je compterai te voir a Paris car je voulais aller là depuis longtemps!
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- *Je compterai te voir* is odd, present is more appropriate in French here as the wish is already current.
- *aller là* should be *y aller*
- The *passé composé* should be used as the action (wanted) is definitive, you would use the *imparfait* "*je voulais*" if you explain later you might change your mind.

Here is then how I would translate that sentence:

> Je compte te voir à Paris, d'autant plus que j'ai toujours voulu y aller.